# Kubernetes: how autoscaling initial readiness is specified?

Tags: kubernetes

My deployment in Kubernetes takes a couple of minutes to initialize, and it has an increased CPU usage during that period. I need a way to wait and disregard CPU metrics from the initialization period for the horizontal autoscaling metrics.

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375952/kubernetes-horizontal-pod-autoscaling-initial-delay) which asks just that, and the answer mentions some relevant flags `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-initial-readiness-delay` and `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-cpu-initialization-period`. But, after reading the [Kubernetes documentation](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) and finding some Kubernetes' [Github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/12657), I still don't quite understand the exact effect from the flags and how to apply them at all: `kubectl autoscale` doesn't seem to accept them in any form.

[This 3rd-party documentation](https://horizontal-pod-autoscaler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/initial-readiness-delay/) demonstrates how to specify these values in yaml but it uses some custom API version and their configuration doesn't work for `autoscaling/v2beta2`.

How these flags are supposed to be put to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set these flags in kube controller manager which is a control plane component of kubernetes

```
--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-initial-readiness-delay duration     Default: 30s
The period after pod start during which readiness changes will be treated as initial readiness.

--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-cpu-initialization-period duration     Default: 5m0s
The period after pod start when CPU samples might be skipped.
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/

Comment: Thank you! Do you possibly know if no such setting possible on the hpa level then?